# Removing slashes from image links in php

Tags: php

I'm getting some images throughout `file_get_contents` function and I receive image links in the following format:

```
https:\/\/assets.domain.com\/uploads\/image\/file\/104572\/container_simple-104572.JPG
```

I've been trying with `stripslash` function but do not work, the output is the same. Even I have tried with `str_replace('\\','/',$string)` and nothing change.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why do you need to remove the slashes?. `str_replace('/','/',$string)` obviously will replace the slashes by slashes => no change in the end.

Comment: Sorry, the slashes were hidden by the comment function.

Comment: oh, so you want to remove the `\\`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wish I could comment...

<strike>As per the manual says</strike>

<strike>mixed str_replace ( mixed $search , mixed $replace , mixed $subject [, int &$count ] )</strike>

<strike>`str_replace`'s second argument is what to replace with. You're replacing `/` with `/`.</strike>

<strike>Use `str_replace('/', '', $subject);`</strike>

---

Since OP updated his question:

Use [`stripslashes()`](http://php.net/stripslashes).

`str_replace` is also a possibility.

Comment: Sorry, there was a mistake due to the comment function which hide the '\' slash.

Answer (score 1):

use following code:

```
$str = 'https:\/\/assets.domain.com\/uploads\/image\/file\/104572\/container_simple-104572.JPG';

echo str_replace("\\", '', $str);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to

```
$string = str_replace('\\','',$string)
```

In many languages, backslashes are used to mark special characters, as `\n` (linebreak),`\t` (tab). To get a backslash itslef in output, you need to type `\\`.